# MYSQL search query optimization from two many-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have three tables.

1. **tbl_post** for a table of posts. (post_idx, post_created, post_title, ...)
2. **tbl_mention** for a table of mentions. (mention_idx, mention_name, mention_img, ...)
3. **tbl_post_mention** for a unique many-to-many relation between the two tables. (post_idx, mention_idx)

For example,

- PostA can have MentionA and MentionB.
- PostB can have MentionA and MentionC.
- PostC cannot have MentionC and MentionC.

tbl_post has about million rows, tbl_mention has less than hundred rows, and tbl_post_mention has a couple of million rows. All three tables are heavily loaded with foreign keys, unique indices, etc.

I am trying to make two separate search queries.

1. **Search for post ids with all the given mention ids[AND condition]**
2. **Search for post ids with any of the given mention ids[OR condition]**

Then join with **tbl_post** and **tbl_mention** to populate with meaningful data, order the results, and return the top n. In the end, I hope to have a **n list of posts with all the data** required for my service to display on the front end.

Here are the respective simpler queries

```
SELECT post_idx 
FROM 
    (SELECT post_idx, count(*) as c 
    FROM tbl_post_mention 
    WHERE mention_idx in (1,95) 
    GROUP BY post_idx) AS A
WHERE c >= 2;
```

The problem with this query is that it is already inefficient before the joins and ordering. This process alone takes 0.2 seconds.

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_idx
FROM tbl_post_mention 
WHERE mention_idx in (1,95);
```

This is a simple index range scan, but because of the IN statement, the query becomes expensive again once you start joining it with other tables.

I tried more complex and "clever" queries and tried indexing different sets of columns with no avail. Are there special syntaxes that I could use in this case? Maybe a clever trick? Partitioning? Or am I missing some fundamental concept here... :(

Send help.

Comment: Optimize the many-to-many schema according to http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

The query you want is this:

```sql
SELECT post_idx 
  FROM tbl_post_mention 
 WHERE mention_idx in (1,95) 
 GROUP BY post_idx
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

The `HAVING` clause does your post-GROUP BY filtering.

The index that will help you is this.

```
CREATE INDEX mentionsdex ON tbl_post_mention (mention_idx, post_idx);
```

It *covers* your query by allowing rapid lookup by `mention_idx` then grouping by `post_idx`.

Often so-called *join tables* with two columns -- like your `tbl_post_mention` -- work most efficiently when they have a pair of indexes with the columns in opposite orders.